# How to loop thru MySQL JSON field

Tags: mysql

Stuck with a problem working on Sphinx indexer. But the question mostly related to MySQL.

I have two tables:

table 1 (id - int, tags - JSON)

```
--------------------  
|   id   |  tags   |  
--------------------  
|    1   |  [1,2]  |  
--------------------
|    2   |   [2]   |
```

table 2 (id - int, value - string)

```
--------------------  
|   id   |  value  |  
--------------------  
|    1   |  tag 1  |  
--------------------
|    2   |  tag 2  |
--------------------
```

I need to write a SELECT query where the tag ID's from the "table 1" will be replaced with the actual values from "table 2". So the result needs to be:

```
--------------------------------
|   id   |     tag_values      |  
--------------------------------  
|    1   |  ["tag 1","tag 2"]  |  
--------------------------------
|    2   |      ["tag 2"]      |
--------------------------------
```

I have already tried googling about looping in SQL and JSON functions but it seems that there is no function which can convert simple JSON to the array.

MySQL v.5.7.23

Any suggestions about how it can be done?

Comment: If you are not going to do any additional query operations on the "desired result", then I would suggest to handle this in your application code (eg: PHP)

Comment: Thank you @MadhurBhaiya. The thing is that this request is for creating Sphinx index and there needs to be only one select query. Also, there can be subqueries.

Comment: If you use MySQL 8.0, you can try `JSON_TABLE()`. Otherwise, you probably shouldn't use JSON for arrays, when you need to expand the array in a query result.